# blackberry .db file missing

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-10

I'm developer of DisciplineXgames, we are building a blackberry app using Phonegap. We are trying to register the keys and get the .csk and .db files.

When we go to register on this page https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html and select "For BlackBerry 10 apps developed using BlackBerry NDK, AIR, or Android, or for BlackBerry PlayBook apps developed using Android." option then it redirects me to login into blackberry developer account and after when I enter password then it gives me .csk file and not .db file. After login I also see a link which says click here but after clicking on that it again takes me back to the select option  link and this continously keep happening and I can't seem to get the .db file or intructions to get it.

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 0):

As you get registered for keys you will get an email with csk files and with instructions, how to install them. db file will be generated upon installation of these keys on your computer.

**UPDATE:**

If nothing helps, post your question on [Official BlackBerry Support Forum for Developers](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Developer-Support-Forums/ct-p/blackberrydev).

On these forums there are BlackBerry (former RIM) employees and they will help you.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did this, but isn't it the *.csi files that they give you?  And then the .csk and .db files are generated from those?

Comment: It was six years ago and I do not recall the exact extensions of files, but when I received keys, db file created upon registration process. I used BlackBerry JDE (BlackBerry Eclipse plugin was not developed yet).

Comment: For BB10 the process was a little different and now they have changed BB10 so that you use your BBID - something I have not done yet.  See: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Code-Signing-Keys-Be-Gone-Welcome-BlackBerry-ID/td-p/2542429